# How to structure recursive descent functions in terms of code sharing?

Tags: parsing, ocaml

I have a grammar that contains:

```
constant ::= integer-literal
| char-literal
∣ string-literal

expression ::= constant

pattern ::= constant | char-literal .. char-literal
```

I am just getting into recursive descent parsing and was wondering how to structure my code to essentially reuse the `constant` parsing. The problem is that when I see a `char-literal`, I can't just parse a constant in the `pattern`.
If the next token is a `..`, it's a different kind of pattern.

Imagine having the following code:

```
let parseConstant p =
  match p.token with
  | Int i -> Const_int (int_of_string i)
  | String s -> Const_string (s, None)
  | Char c -> Const_char c
```

How would I structure the `parseExpression` and `parsePattern` function to reuse the `parseConstant`? Or do I just create a different `parsePatternConstantMaybeDotDotOtherGrammarThing` function for patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I might do is to have the code for `pattern` call `parseConstant`. Then look at the next token. If it's `..`, then if the constant is a character constant you can parse the rest of the character range. If the constant is not a character constant you have a syntax error. If the next token isn't `..` you are done parsing your pattern.

The reason that recursive descent parsers are low stress is that you can code up any odd cases directly. You don't have to make them fit a parsing framework--it's just code. The price to pay is that you have to write the code, and be careful to get it right.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!